# Максимальное значение в многомерном массиве

Tags: jquery

Возможно ли используя `Math.max.apply` найти максимальное значение `priority`, где `active` не равно `0`?

```
var info = [
    {id: 1, active: 0, priority: 1},
    {id: 2, active: 1, priority: 100},
    {id: 3, active: 0, priority: 55},
    {id: 4, active: 1, priority: 170}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const info = [
  {id: 1, active: 0, priority: 1},
  {id: 2, active: 1, priority: 100},
  {id: 3, active: 0, priority: 55},
  {id: 4, active: 1, priority: 170}
];

const max0 = Math.max.apply(Math, info.filter((item) => item.active).map((item) => item.priority));

const max1 = Math.max(...info.filter((item) => item.active).map((item) => item.priority));

console.log(max0, max1);
```

Comment: А можно в этом примере определить у какого `id` максимальное число?

Comment: завести временную переменную-словарь и класть соответствие priority => id

Comment: А можно кодом? Там явно не так просто.